# How to Configure the Where clause in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to make `WHERE` clause configured in `app.config` so I followed the below way..

`app.config`:

```
<add key="TYPE" value="'Admin','Manager'"/>
```

Reading it like below:

```
var types = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TYPE"];
var whereClause = types.Replace("'", "\"");
```

In query:

```
var data = (from entry in db.TestTable
            where new[] {whereClause}.Contains(entry.Name)
            select new
            {
              Id = entry.Id,
              FirstName = entry.FName,
              LastName = entry.LName   
            }).ToList();
```

It is not throwing any error also not returning any data.

What I am doing wrong here ? is there any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`whereClause` is a single string. In your example it ends up being the literal string `"Admin","Manager"` (not TWO strings, but one string including double-quotes and a comma).

You are creating an "array" that consists of *that single string* and seeing if it "contains" `entry.Name`.  So unless there is an entry whose name is *exactly* `"Admin","Manager"` the `where` clause will return false.

Rather than replacing the single quotes with double quotes split the string and remove the single quotes altogether:

```
var whereClause = types.Replace("'", "").Split(",");
```

and change your query to

```
var data = (from entry in db.TestTable
            where whereClause.Contains(entry.Name)
            select new
            {
              Id = entry.Id,
              FirstName = entry.FName,
              LastName = entry.LName   
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for detail explanation and answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're searching the string, `"Admin", "Manager"` for the entry. Tryparsing the app setting into an array?

```
<add key="TYPE" value="Admin|Manager"/>
```

Then

```
var types = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TYPE"];
var whereClause = types.Split('|');
```

Then proceed as before. This should generate SQL like;

```
select id, firstname, lastname
from testtable
where name in ("Admin", "Manager")
```